# Does a homeomorphism take $F_\sigma$ sets to $F_\sigma$ sets?

Tags: general-topology

I know it is true for the real line. So I guess it will be true for metric spaces too. But what about general topological spaces?

Comment: The very idea of a homeomorphisn is a map that preserves all topological properties. What do you doubt this and what attempt have you made to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a homeomorphism, with $g:Y\to X$ being the inverse. Suppose that $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of closed subsets of $X$. Then, $$f\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n\right)=g^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n\right)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}g^{-1}(C_n).$$ Since $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(C_n)$ is closed in $Y$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Hence, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}g^{-1}(C_n)$ is $F_{\sigma}$.

---

TL;DR: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ can be displayed as a countable union of closed sets, then the homeomorphism will take this countable union of closed sets into another countable union of closed sets (since a homeomorphism preserves closed sets and set operations), which will give you $f(A)$, and so $f(A)$ is indeed $F_\sigma$

Answer (score 0):

AN homeomorphism is bi-continuous:
SO its inverse is continuous. Then image of closed set is a closed set.

Also the image of an union is the union of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Homeomorphic spaces are topologically indistinguishable, and even a homeomorphism between distinct spaces is indistinguishable from the identity of a space to itself. Ultimately, anything defined via topology (such as $F_\sigma$) is preserved under homeomorphisms.